"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions."
I'm running a python file "data_prep.py" in which it prepares and load image data for use in a machine learning model, particularly for classification tasks involving images of different categories. However, Ive been getting an error everytime I tried to return the value in prep_and_load_data():
import math
import os 
from random import shuffle
import constants as CONST 
import cv2
import pickle
import glob
import numpy as np

def get_size_statistics():
    heights = []
    widths = []
    img_count = 0
    DIR = CONST.TRAIN_DIR2
    for img in os.listdir(CONST.TRAIN_DIR2):
        path = os.path.join(DIR, img)
        data = cv2.imread(path)
        # data = np.array(Image.open(path))
        heights.append(data.shape[0])
        widths.append(data.shape[1])
        img_count += 1
    avg_height = sum(heights) / len(heights)
    avg_width = sum(widths) / len(widths)
    print("Average Height: " + str(avg_height))
    print("Max Height: " + str(max(heights)))
    print("Min Height: " + str(min(heights)))
    print('\n')
    print("Average Width: " + str(avg_width))
    print("Max Width: " + str(max(widths)))
    print("Min Width: " + str(min(widths)))


def label_img(name):
    # print(name)
    word_label = name.split('.')[0]
    # word_label = 'cat'
    label = CONST.LABEL_MAP[word_label]
    label_arr = np.zeros(2)
    label_arr[label] = 1
    return label_arr
def prep_and_load_data():
    DIR2 = CONST.TRAIN_DIR2
    data = []
    image_paths = os.listdir(DIR2)
    shuffle(image_paths)
    count = 0
    max_images = 100 
    for img_path in image_paths:
        # Skip directories and non-image files
        if not img_path.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')):
            print(f"Skipping non-image file or directory: {img_path}")
            continue
        
        label = label_img(img_path)
        path = os.path.join(DIR2, img_path)
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (CONST.IMG_SIZE, CONST.IMG_SIZE))
        image = image.astype('float') / 255.0 
        data.append([image, label])
        count += 1
        # print(count)
        if count == max_images:
            print(f"Reached the limit of {max_images} images.")
            break
    shuffle(data)
    print(len(data))
    print('done')
    print(np.array(data))
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prep_and_load_data()
    

The error in questions is this, as I'm struggling to determine what went wrong as ths is a pre-existing code I've found on Github for learning purposes: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (100, 2) + inhomogeneous part."
For the record, the constant import is taken from this code:
TRAIN_DIR2 = 'Code\\dogs-vs-cats\\train\\train'
TEST_DIR2 = 'Code\\dogs-vs-cats\\test1\\test1'
CAT_LBL = 0
DOG_LBL = 1
CAT = 'cat'
DOG = 'dog'
LABEL_MAP = {
    CAT: CAT_LBL,
    DOG: DOG_LBL
}
DATA_SIZE = 18_000
IMG_SIZE = 110
SPLIT_RATIO = 0.8

Is there a way to fix this?

What line of code is failing? Paste the full trace back if available.

The error means you have a 'ragged array'.  That is, data that can't be made into a regular numeric array.  Where does the error occur?

@hpaulj the error traces from here: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\Code\data_prep.py", line 76, in 
prep_and_load_data()
File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\Code\data_prep.py", line 72, in prep_and_load_data
print(np.array(data))

np.array(data) is trying to convert the data list into a numeric array,and it can't.  Examine the content of the list.  I suspect combining the images and labels into one list is (part of) the problem.

Using other peoples code that you don't understand and haven't tested step by step is 'dangerous'.

@nneonneo  the error traces from here: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\Code\data_prep.py", line 76, in  prep_and_load_data() File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\Code\data_prep.py", line 72, in prep_and_load_data print(np.array(data))

@hpaulj I did my best to understand how the code works step by step, but the author of the code didnt write much about how it should run, such as for example, calling tensorboard in main.py, even though the import hasn't been called for some reason. AFter some tuning, I was wondering if this could work: data = np.array(prep_and_load_data(),dtype=object)

how old is that code?Handling of 'ragged' arrays has changed over time in numpy.

Another common problem with loading images, is having a mix of color and b/w images.  resize doesn't correct for that.  np.array(data, dtype=object) might run, but doesn't correct the underlying shape incompatibility.  This is a relatively common error message, but the exact fix depends on your data.

@hpaulj from its github page (https://github.com/anubhavparas/image-classification-using-cnn/tree/master/Code) it's from 4 years ago. As for the data, it's taken from the input data file that I extracted from the page. With prep_data.py, it loads training images to the machine and then uses test images in main.py to put use in its function to see if it works or not.

4yrs is old enough that np.array(prep_and_load_data()) might have worked without the dtype=object addition.  Notice the extra work he does to separate images and labels for training and testing. This is dated code and not the best for learning. An experienced programmer can probably make it work, but a beginner will be confused.

@hpaulj I see. So is it better to write it like this: data = np.array(prep_and_load_data(), dtype=object)? When I ran the code with this edit, the error didn't come up but I wonder why it fixed it.

Did you look at the resulting array?  shape, dtype?  How does that differ from a 'normal' array, e.g. np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

Normally numpy makes a regular numeric dtype array.  Object dtype is a way around this for some inputs.  It used to be that numpy tried this automatic fallback.  Now you have to specify it.  Object dtype arrays can be useful, but are really are little better than nested lists (and in some ways worse).

I see, thanks. I got the code working now.
